# Looking for public dataset for stock market that is updated daily

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, stock

I want to do some modelling and data visualization on historical stock data, including price, volume, financials, etc. Is there a public dataset available for stock price history? I looked at a few (Yahoo, Kaggle and Tiingo), but either they have a high cost, are missing some of the key financial information, or are not sure they would be reliable and up to date. Free would be preferred, also established and reliable. If not, what are some good options for collecting the data myself? Maybe web scraping, public APIs, etc. I plan to use this data in a machine learning project I am building.

Answer (score 4):

In python, there are many libraries that can be used to get the stock market data. The most common set of data is the price volume data. These data can be used to create quant strategies, technical strategies, or very simple buy-and-hold strategies. The different Python libraries which provide stock market data are as follows:

**Price-Volume Data**

- Daily data

  - Yahoo finance
  - Quandl
- Minute level data

  - Alpha vantage

**Futures & options price-volume data for Indian markets**

- NSEPy

[Python Code and Overview of the Libraries can be found here](https://www.quora.com/Where-can-I-get-stock-market-data-set-for-data-analysis)

---

[Stock Market Data](https://datahub.io/collections/stock-market-data)

Find and Explore ready-to-use Stock Market Datasets

---

[Top 10 Stock Market Datasets for Machine Learning](https://lionbridge.ai/datasets/top-10-stock-market-datasets-for-machine-learning/)

---

[NIFTY-50 Stock Market Data (2000 - 2020)](https://www.kaggle.com/rohanrao/nifty50-stock-market-data)

Stock price data of the fifty stocks in NIFTY-50 index from NSE India

---

[Financial data](https://intrinio.com/)

Data your way. Choose your access method and pay only for the data you need.

---

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Wondering if any of these also include assets to debts, earnings by quarter, ROA, ROI, etc. I may want to compare stock prices vs the value of the company.

Comment: Similar libraries are available in R and perl (and probably many other languages)

Comment: Intrinio is not open data (this site is about open data). None of your other links are updated daily, which is the requirement of the question.